# How to post message to wall (Android + FBConnect)

Tags: android, facebook

I need to post message to a wall using FBConnect library for Android. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what your looking for:
http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/wiki/CodeSnippets